# Summing along a function in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, sum

Is it possible to place a linear function over a 2D array and sum all the elements in the 2D array that coincide with the function? So for example, I would have a 2D array shaped say (400, 500). Now somewhere, I would overlap a linear function which stretches from the bottom of the 2D array towards the top. I now only want to sum the elements of the 2D array that overlap with the linear line.

Is there a fast way to sum only the elements of the 2D array that coincide with the linear line? I have been able to do so by using a for loop within a for loop. However, this already takes quit some time. Especially if I want to start applying this trick to even larger arrays.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output of what you are looking for?

Comment: Probably!  Post an simplified example 2D array, the function, and expected output.  As it stands the question is a bit vague (what's a "linear line")?

Comment: I take it you're asking for something akin to a discrete line integral, is that right?

Comment: The 2D array in its maximal form can be defined as: `numpy.arange((1002 * 1004)).reshape(1002, 1004)`. The linear line is defined by `x cos(phi) + y sin(phi)`, here phi is in the order of pi/3.

Comment: What are `x` and `y`?  What their relation to the 2d array?

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on how *exactly* you define the line, and what array locations count as being "on" the line. But one simple approach would be to use a boolean mask. You can define a mask along a line pretty easily using `numpy.mgrid`:

```
>>> grid = numpy.mgrid[0:5,0:5]
>>> grid
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]])
```

As you can see, this is a grid of x and y values, and you can then relate them in an equation like so:

```
>>> grid[0] == 2 * grid[1]
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> grid[0] == grid[1]
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> grid[0] == grid[1] / 2
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Note that you'll probably have to do some careful thinking about why `grid[0] == grid[1] / 2` gives a "continuous" line, while `grid[0] == 2 * grid[1]` does not, and figure out precisely what behavior you want. (With a slightly more complex equation, you could specify a tolerance value that would allow you to create lines of different thicknesses.)

Then you can use the resulting mask to do a sum:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> a[grid[0] == grid[1] / 2]
array([ 0,  1,  7,  8, 14])
>>> a[grid[0] == grid[1] / 2].sum()
30
```

This is a lot faster than nested for loops because `numpy` is very fast. But it still does the same number of operations.

Another approach might be to directly calculate `y` values from `x` values. The advantage of this is that it doesn't have to do as many operations, and so will be faster for very very large arrays:

```
>>> x = numpy.arange(5)
>>> y = x * 2
>>> valid_indices = (x < 5) & (y < 5)
>>> a[x[valid_indices], y[valid_indices]]
array([ 0,  7, 14])
```

Then just use `.sum()`. To show what the line looks like now:

```
>>> a[x[valid_indices], y[valid_indices]] = -1
>>> a
array([[-1,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6, -1,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, -1],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Again, as you can see, there are gaps in the line; if you want to remove those gaps you'll have to change it up a bit by "stretching" the x or y values. Here's a function that does so using a simple slope-intercept specification. You'll still need to add special-casing for `0` and infinite slopes, but this does a lot of the necessary work, and produces a nice, smooth line in all the cases I tested it against:

```
def linear_index(slope, intercept, x_range, y_range):
    if numpy.abs(slope) < 1:
        intercept = intercept / slope
        slope = 1 / slope
        y, x = linear_index(slope, intercept, y_range, x_range)
        return x, y

    x_min, x_max = x_range
    y_min, y_max = y_range
    x = numpy.linspace(x_min, x_max - 1, (x_max - x_min - 1) * slope + 1)
    y = x * slope + intercept
    print x, y
    valid_indices = (y >= y_min) & (y < y_max)
    return x[valid_indices].astype(int), y[valid_indices].astype(int)
```

Given an adequate understanding of the [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), you should have no problem at all converting an `(r, theta)` pair into slope intercept form. Still, if you need a thicker line, this might not be the best approach.

Comment: The linear function I want to use depends on a varying angle. The linear line is defined by `x cos(phi) + y sin(phi)`

Comment: @user2776885, now I'm more confused. `x cos(phi) + y sin(phi)` is a 2-d function of x and y -- it's not a line.

Comment: It is the Hough Transform which is used to represent a straight line (y = ax + b). However, the Hough transform considers the characteristics of the straight line not as image points (x1, y1), (x2, y2), but instead considers the slope parameter a and the intercept parameter b.

Comment: @user2776885, well, it's not quite the Hough Transform. Go look at the [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) wikipedia page. It shows that the formula you're supplying is incomplete. If you understand that page, it should be _very_ easy to adapt my answer to your problem.